# SFINAE conditional and constructor argument types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, sfinae

I have encountered the following technique that allows the construction of a wrapper object around `T`, but from objects of type `U`, if `T` is constructible from `U`:

```
template< typename T >
struct S {
    template< typename U,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<
                  std::is_constructible< T, U >::value > >
    explicit S (U&& arg) : value (arg)
        { }
    ...
};
```

IIUC, the type `U` used in the `is_constructible` test can be different from the cv-qualified type of `arg`.
Is it possible that the SFINAE test could fail although the expression `value(arg)` is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that the SFINAE test could fail although the expression value(arg) is valid?

The way you wrote `S`: yes, it's possible.
It follows a minimal, (not) working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template< typename T >
struct S {
    template< typename U
              , typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible< T, U >::value >
    > explicit S (U&& arg) : value{arg} {}

    T value;
};

struct A {};
struct B {
    B(A &) {}
};

int main() {
    S<B> s(A{});
}
```

The code above doesn't compile, but it does compile if you comment out the following line:

```
, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible< T, U >::value >
```

The problem is that you are not forwarding the constructor parameter. Instead, you are using an lvalue reference to a variable of type rvalue reference to `A` (that is `arg`) as an argument for `value`.
`B` is not constructible from an rvalue reference to `A` and the sfinae expression fails (correctly), but you are not actually using such a reference to construct the parameter, so removing the sfinae expression it works.
In fact, `B` is constructible from an lvalue reference to `A`, that is what you are using when you write `value{arg}`.

---

You should rather write `S` as it follows:

```
#include<utility>

// ...

template< typename T >
struct S {
    template< typename U
              , typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible< T, U >::value >
    > explicit S (U&& arg) : value (std::forward<U>(arg)) { }

    T value;
};
```

Note the use of `std::forward` to actually forward the parameters with the right types.
This at least solves the above mentioned issue and it should give you the guarantees you were looking for.